# Missing ios distribution signing identity not expired certificate

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, keychain, ios-provisioning

[image]

[image]

I'm having so many issues archiving and uploading my project to the apple store for submission.  Probably have gone through changing the bundle identifier-- creating a certificate, updating the app ID and creating a provisioning profile 5 times already.

When I try to validate the project after I've archived it I get the error missing ios distribution signing identity for signing identity (Me)...

Is it because my iphone distribution says 'this certificate has an invalid user'?  How do I fix that?  I downloaded the certificate link they suggested and used it to create a certificate.  Very stuck and frustrated.

Every time I try to change this section to be the iOS Distribution Identity and corresponding Provisioning Profile it says it's unable to find a matching UUID for the provisioning profile.  Not sure if that's helpful but it seems like something is mis-configured, just not sure where to look or where to start over, or if there is some lurking configuration from an older mistake that is screwing me up.
[image]

Comment: followed the instructions here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16155613/a-valid-provisioning-profile-matching-the-applications-identifier-could-not-be  to no avail :(

Comment: solved!  there was another version of the expired certificated located in the system keychain directory.  Phew!

Comment: Step 1: Open Keychain access, delete "Apple world wide Developer relations certification authority" (which expires on 14th Feb 2016) from both "Login" and "System" sections. If you can't find it, use “Show Expired Certificates” in the View menu.

Comment: delete the old certificate in login and system menu then tell it work for you

Answer (score 1):

delete all the certificates and provisions profiles, reinstall all the certificates and profiles. this might resolve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Update the apple developer certificate

1->Open keychain

2->Go to view - Show expired certificate

3->Delete the red mark certificate  "Apple Worldwide Developer Relations Certificate Authority"

4->Download  https://developer.apple.com/certificationauthority/AppleWWDRCA.cer

5->Install it and now see if you are able to use certificate or not

More detail explanation [This certificate has an invalid issuer Apple Push Services](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35390072/this-certificate-has-an-invalid-issuer-apple-push-services)

[image]