# iOS app submission - test url

Tags: ios, ios7

We have built a iOS application and we are going to submit it to App store. Inside our app we have hardcoded the url of the webservice.
Our client wants to do something like this.
For the review he wants set that url to the webservice in the dev and after approval to change it to production. As he doesn't want to create fake accounts and data in the production database.

Is there any setting or something to do such a thing for the approval without changing our code.

Thanks

Comment: Do you need to log in to the app at some point?

Answer (score 1):

Hardcode a specific URL in your app. Then setup your web server so that URL gets redirected to the "real" URL. Before your app is in the store, have the URL redirect to the development URL. Once your app has been approved and it goes live, change the URL to redirect to the production URL.

This is basically a single line change in the web server's config file.

This gets a little trickier if you need to repeat the process each time you submit an update. You probably will want the review of the update to go back to the development URL. This will probably required that you pass a version number as part of the URL (which you should do anyway incase the API of your URL changes over time).

Answer (score 0):

You can check whether on not the app is in AppStore. Check out this answer for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/a/17627239/2604030

Answer (score 0):

I am hoping you haven't also hardcoded a password in there.

However, unless this is a very long-term, robust service, also hardcoding your database server details in there is also a bit dangerous.

Consider writing them to NSUserDefaults but having a failover service.

For example, if the server doesn't respond, have a different server you can hit to get a new database server address.

This would allow you to setup a test server, kill it after review, and have new users go to the new server.

Another approach is, if you have a way to push notifications to the devices or have a status check that they do, add extra metadata to that check message so you can pass through an update to the server address.

Querying a separate server for important metadata is a common technique - it lets you have some flexibility and respond to emergencies.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just KISS and set the URL in NSUserDefaults or a plist (i.e. validation=URL1, validated=URL2 or something). This way your URL is configuration-based and not embedded in your code. You could use Sebyddd's response in your code to determine which URL you grab at runtime

Comment: The solution in the link i've posted doesn't actually help you get the result at runtime.