# Multiple certificates per Distribution Provisioning Profile

Tags: iphone, xcode, provisioning-profile

When you create a Development Provisioning Profile you can select multiple certificates to include in it. Is there a way to do this for a Distribution Provisioning Profile?

Or do I need to have a separate one per Distribution Certificate?

Answer (score 1):

No you can not select multiple certificate for a provisioning profile when you create of edit from developer portal.
Also have a look over the link detail description there regards certificate I hope you can get the answer as per your requirement 
[Certificates and profile organization for multiple products](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15623626/certificates-and-profile-organization-for-multiple-products)